# Teamcity-2018.2+Not publishing the Jar to jFrog Artifactory + maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, teamcity

I have few dependencies in my pom.xml file and used below assembly-plugin to create a jar with all dependencies.
Create created a final jar as **{{artifact-id}}-{{version}}-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptorRefs>
                                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                    </descriptorRefs>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

From Teamcity, i have added Maven build step and enabled artifactory settings as below,

Artifactory server URL: https://artifactory.***/artifactory
Target repository: libs-release-local
Target snapshot repository: libs-snapshot-local

And added following maven lifecycle - clean test package. here on Success, it publish the jar to respective folder in artifactory with **{{artifact-id}}-{{version}}-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

Case:
Need to deploy the jar without "-jar-with-dependencies" to artifactory

Changes in Pom:
Did following changes,

```
                             <configuration>
                                <descriptorRefs>
                                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                </descriptorRefs>
```

> ```
> <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>                                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
> ```

```
                            </configuration>
```

Issue:
With above changes, it is working fine with maven package command in local environment.

But while executing from teamcity it is **NOT** publishing the Jar to the Artifactory..

could you please redirect to resolve the issue?

Comment: Calling maven with `package` will not send your artifact to artifactory. You need to call `deploy` for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion JF, but it works fine when final name and appendAssemblyId is not set even with package phase.

Comment: If `package` deploys artifacts to artifactory, there is something wrong. Or maybe, you have an additional step in your TeamCity that handles the upload. Package should never send artifacts to artifactory.

Comment: As part of Teamcity Maven Build - using "Deploy Artifacts To Artifactory" plugin the artifactory is been deployed to our artifactory repository.

So when we publish with <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId> it publishing the artifact to artifactory successfully - with appending -Jar-with-dependecies.

but if we make <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId> then the teamcity is not considering the jar and NOT deploying to artifactory.

Comment: is there any other way to deploy the artifact with out jar-with-dependecies not appended at the end of jar?